# Is there a way for Protractor Cucumber to only rerun failed browser tests?

Tags: angular, automation, protractor

I'm using **protractor flake** and running browser tests in parallel using selenium grid. I don't want to rerun all the browser tests if one of the browser failed.

Is there a way to set in the configuration to only rerun the browser that failed?
Protractor config file

```
exports.config = {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        getPageTimeout: 600000,
        allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        framework: 'custom',
        // path relative to the current config file
        frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
        multiCapabilities:
        [{
          'browserName': 'chrome',
          specs: 'features/chrome/*.feature'
        },
        {
          'browserName': 'firefox',
          specs: 'features/firefox/*.feature'
        }],
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:8080',
        ignoreSynchronization: true,
        cucumberOpts: {
          strict: true,
          require: [
            'hooks/hooks.js',
            'specs/*Spec.js'
          ],
          tags: [
            "@runThis", 
            "~@ignoreThis"
          ],
          profile: false,
          format: 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json',
          resultJsonOutputFile: 'e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'
        },
        onPrepare: async function() {

          const fs = require('fs');
          const path = require('path');

          const directory = 'e2e/reports';

          //cleans up the json results from the previous build when using node flake
          fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (const file of files) {
              fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), err => {
                if (err) throw err;
              });
            }
          });

          var chai = require('chai');
          chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
          global.expect = chai.expect;
          browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
          await browser.manage().window().maximize();
          browser.waitForAngular();           
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000); 

        },
        onComplete: function() {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for that you need to put the reporter rerun with the name of the file you want to give to the ouput:

```
format: ['pretty', 'rerun:@rerun.txt']
```

then you have to run protractor with the cucumber options specifying the filename:

```
protractor test/cucumber/conf/cucumber1Conf.js --cucumberOpts.rerun test/cucumber/@rerun.txt
```

More information about it can be found here: https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/89

Comment: Thanks for the comment! How do I put in my current config? I have mine set to format: 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'. So would I just add it to the array? format: ['pretty', 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json', 'rerun:@rerun.txt']?

Comment: Yes, it'd be a new item inside the format property of the config object (which can be an array):
`exports.config = {

... format: [ <all the reporters go here> ], ... 

}`